# Transforming $x^2y''(x) +Axy' (x) +Bx^{\delta}y(x)=0$ into bessel-function

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, bessel-functions

Given the equation :

$x^2y''(x) +Axy' (x) +Bx^{\delta}y(x)=0$

Need to transform it to bessel-function.

**My attempt:**

I substitute :$x=z^{\alpha}$ so
$(z^{\alpha})^2y''(x)+A(z^{\alpha}) y' (x)+B(z^{\alpha}) ^{\delta}y(x)=0$

But I'm having difficulty to write it in terms of $y(z)$ especially the $y''(x)$ term.

How do I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: That's not an equation.

Comment: @zugzug I edited.

Answer (score 1):

The correct substitution is
$$
y(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{A}{2}} f\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{B} x^{\delta /2}}{\delta }\right)
$$
This transforms your equation to the Bessel one for $f(z)$ with the index $\nu=\frac{A-1}{\delta }$.

Comment: Thank you, but my substitution can work as well, maybe not directly as yours. But my problem is to express y'' in term of z. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Did you try to (i) substitute this expression y(x) into your equation, (ii) evaluate the derivatives, (iii) put $x^{\delta/2}\to \frac{z\delta}{2\sqrt{B}}$ in the result?

Comment: I think it would help if you show how you try to do it, with an example of one of the terms in the equation.

Comment: I put more details

Comment: Sorry this is completely off. Let me consider the term with the second derivative and use your substitution $x=z^\alpha$.
$$y(x)=f(x^{1/\alpha})$$
$$y''(x)=\frac{x^{\frac{2}{\alpha }-2} f''\left(x^{1/\alpha }\right)}{\alpha ^2}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{\alpha }-1\right) x^{\frac{1}{\alpha }-2} f'\left(x^{1/\alpha }\right)}{\alpha }$$
Turning back to $z$:
$$
\frac{z^{2-2 \alpha } f''(z)}{\alpha ^2}+\frac{(\alpha -1) z^{1-2 \alpha } f'(z)}{\alpha ^2}
$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105802/discussion-between-stokes-line-and-deb-u).

Comment: Thanks I got it. Tho I think your last term is 1-a not a-1

Comment: You are right, it is a misprint.